# Question of Objective C on iphone

Tags: objective-c

```
-(void)touchesBegan :(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 [textValue resignFirstResponder];
 [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

can someone explain me the meaning of this method???

Answer (score 2):

```
[textValue resignFirstResponder];
```

Usually used to hide the keyboard if `textValue` control has focus at the moment.

```
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
```

Calls the same method of parent class to preserve standard touch handling.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html);

> Tells the receiver when one or more
>   fingers touch down in a view or
>   window.
>
> The primary event-handling methods for
>   touches are touchesBegan:withEvent:,
>   touchesMoved:withEvent:,
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:, and
>   touchesCancelled:withEvent:. The
>   parameters of these methods associate
>   touches with their events, especially
>   touches that are new or have
>   changed and thus allow responder
>   objects to track and handle the
>   touches as the delivered events
>   progress through the phases of a
>   multi-touch sequence.